# Find the area of the shaded region of this figure

Tags: geometry

[image]

Find the area of the shaded region. (Each arcs of circles in the figure are assumed to be $\frac{1}{4}$ of a full circle)

Comment: This problem is classic......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the area of 4 remaining parts and subtract them from the area of the square.
[image]

Comment: Well done, that is an olympic degree question.

Comment: @Kitiara, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[HINT](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*%20integral(sqrt(1-x%5E2)-1%2F2,1%2F2,sqrt(3)%2F2)):
$$
A=4\int_{1/2}^{\sqrt 3/2}\sqrt{1-x^2}-1/2dx = 1-\sqrt 3-\frac \pi 3 = 0.31515
$$

Comment: Your answer is the best and should be the one that is accepted. The result is the same as that one and, oh, so much better!

Comment: I'm not getting correct results with this one.[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*int+1%2F2+to+sqrt(3)%2F2+(sqrt(1-(10)%5E2)-1%2F2+dx)

Comment: Check the result.

Comment: @CyeWaldman, And oh! here is categorized for geometry :)

Comment: The first time i faced this problem i didnt know algebra!. I just made it this way as vengeance...

Comment: You are assuming `x = 1` in this form.

Comment: @Kitiara I doesn't matter. The area must necessarily scale as $x^2$.

Comment: @Seyed Thank you for pointing that out. By way apology, please accept my upvote.

Comment: @CyeWaldman, Thank you very much for your upvote Sir, and please believe me I was just joking, I put a smiley at the end of my comment.

Comment: @Seyed No offense taken. I was exhibiting my prejudice about geometry because the notation ABD, etc. drives me crazy. I cannot read a paper without constantly referring back to the figure to see what it means. That prejudice almost keep me from participating in this paper (http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fnotices%2F201509%2Frnoti-p1036.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEvWsJAD1_j3IgvH5GcAhvGK_Jphg) because I had to read and understand several of Archimedes works in The Method.

Answer (score 1):

$FC=2x\sin 15°$

$\sin 15°=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos 30°}{2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$FC=2x\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}=x\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{ \sqrt{2}}\\
Area_{FHGC}=FC^2=\left(x\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-1}{ \sqrt{2}}\right)^2=x^2(2-\sqrt 3)$

$area_{red}=\dfrac{1}{2} x^2 (t-\sin t)\\
area_{red}=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)
$

$Area=x^2\left[2-\sqrt 3+2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right]\\
Area=x^2\left(1+\dfrac{\pi}{3}-\sqrt{3}\right)$

[image]

Comment: There is a mistake, i don't get the correct answer when i replace X with another number.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works

Comment: Now it is correct, the second way of solving the question. Well done.